# Ms. A selects a number $X$ randomly from the uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$. Then Mr. B repeatedly, and independently, draws numbers

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value, conditional-expectation, geometric-distribution

**Ms. A selects a number $X$ randomly from the uniform distribution
on $[0, 1]$. Then Mr. B repeatedly, and independently, draws numbers
$Y_1, Y_2, ...$ from the uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$, until he gets a number
larger than $\frac{X}{2}$, then stops. The expected sum of the number Mr. B draws, given $X = x$, equals?**

The answer to this is $\frac{1}{(2-x)}$. I got the expected number of draws as $ln 4$ by taking $Z$ as a random variable for the number of draws which follows geometric distribution whith parameter $p= 1 - \frac{x}{2}$. But I don't know how to calculate for expected sum of $Y_{i}$ . Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although, you didn't include `self-study` tag, I first give you two hints and then full solution. You may stop reading after first or second hint and try youself.

**Hint 1**:

For $a \in (0,1)$ we have $$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} ma^m = \frac{a}{(1-a)^2}$$

**Hint 2**:

Let $K$ be number of numbers drawn by Mr. B. And let your "target variable", $E(Y_1+\ldots+Y_K | X=x)$ be denoted by $Z$. Notice, this is a random variable, not a real number (since $K$ is a random variable). Then, by the law of total expectation, $E(Z) = E(E(Z|K))$.

**Full solution**:

$K$ follows, as you mentioned, geometric distribution with probability of success $p=1-\frac{x}{2}$. So 
$$E(Z) = E(E(Z|K)) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} E(Z|K=k)P(K=k)$$

and $$P(K=k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p = \left(\frac x2\right)^{k-1}\left(1-\frac x2\right)$$.

Let's focus on $E(Z|K=k)$. It is now $E(Y_1+\ldots+Y_k | X=x, K=k)$. Notice lower case $k$ here!!! Since $Y$'s are independent this equals
$$E(Y_1 | X=x, K=k)+\ldots+E(Y_k | X=x, K=k)$$.

Conditioning on $X=x$ and $K=k$ means that $Y_1, \ldots, Y_{k-1}$ are drawn uniformly from $\left[0,\frac x2\right)$ and $Y_k$ is drawn uniformly from $\left(\frac x2, 1\right]$.

So $$E(Y_1 | X=x, K=k)=\ldots=  E(Y_{k-1} | X=x, K=k) = \frac x4$$

and $$E(Y_k | X=x, K=k) = \frac{1+\frac x2}{2} = \frac{2+x}4$$

Putting all this together:
$$ E(Z|K=k) = (k-1)\frac x4 + \frac{2+x}4$$

And
$$E(Z) =  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( (k-1)\frac x4 + \frac{2+x}4 \right) P(K=k) =   \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  (k-1)\frac x4 P(K=k) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{2+x}4  P(K=k)$$

Second part is easy (last equality uses the fact that sum of probability mass function adds up to 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{2+x}4  P(K=k) = \frac{2+x}4\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}    P(K=k)= \frac{2+x}4 $$

*To get this, you can also use the fact, that Mr. B always draws one last number from $\left(\frac x2, 1\right]$, no matter what value of $K$ took.*

First part is only a bit harder:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  (k-1)\frac x4 P(K=k) =  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  (k-1)\frac x4 \left(\frac x2\right)^{k-1}\left(1-\frac x2\right)$$

Move everything that do not depend on $k$ in fornt of sum to get: $$  \frac x4 \left(1-\frac x2\right)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  (k-1) \left(\frac x2\right)^{k-1}$$

Introduce $m=k-1$:
$$  \frac x4 \left(1-\frac x2\right)\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}  m \left(\frac x2\right)^m$$

Use hint 1 with $a=\frac x2$:
$$  \frac x4 \left(1-\frac x2\right)\frac{\frac x2}{(1-\frac x2)^2}$$

To finally get
$$  \frac {x^2}{8(1-\frac x2)} =\frac {x^2}{8(\frac {2-x}2)} =\frac {x^2}{4(2-x)}   $$

And add second part (the easy one):
$$ \frac {x^2}{4(2-x)}  + \frac{2+x}4  = \frac {x^2}{4(2-x)}  + \frac{(2+x)(2-x)}{4(2-x)} = \frac {x^2 + (4-x^2)}{4(2-x)} = \frac 4{4(2-x)} = \frac 1{2-x}$$

WHOAH!!!!

Comment: Genius!!!! I'm more than grateful! :D

Comment: My pleasure. Really. I enjoyed this "riddle" ☺

Answer (score 2):

Another angle of solution (summing not with P(K=k) but P(K>=k)):

$$\begin{array}\\
E(\sum Y_k) = \sum E(Y_k) & = \sum_{k=1}^\infty E(Y_k|K>=k) \cdot  P(K>=k) \\
& =   \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{x}{2} \right)^k \\
& = \frac{1}{2-x} 
\end{array}$$

Comment: Could you elaborate? I didn't get the working

Comment: You will make a k-th draw in a fraction $\left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{k-1}$ of the time,  and in that fraction of the time it will contribute 1/2 to the expected value of the sum. You could see the value of $Y_k$ as being distributed as a mixture distribution of a uniform distribution (between 0 and 1, when it is drawn) and a constant value (0, when it is not drawn). $$E(Y_k) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x}{2} \right)^{k-1} $$

Comment: Okay, help me understand this,  if you're including the 'equal to' case in the inequality, shouldn't $P(K\ge k)$ include the $K^{th}$ success (with probability $1- \frac{x}{2}$) and not just the $k-1$ failures (with probability $\frac{x}{2}$) that occured prior to it?

Comment: It includes *both* the possibility of success and failure $$0.5 \left(1-\frac{x}{2} \right) + 0.5 \left( \frac{x}{2} \right) $$

Comment: The formula $\sum_{k=1}^\infty E(Y_k|K>=k) \cdot  P(K>=k)$ is weird since $Y_k$ depends on $k$.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent it is less weird if you consider a slight different interpretation of the $Y_k$ (as a mixture distribution). You define $Y_k=0$ if $K<k$, such that $Y_k$ always has a value even if you did not pick a $k-th$ number. The CDF would be:

$$F(x)_{Y_k} = \begin{cases} 0 & \qquad \text{for } x < 0 \\
1-\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)^{k-1} & \qquad \text{for } x = 0  \\
1-(1-x)\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)^{k-1} & \qquad \text{for } 0 < x < 1 & \\
1 & \qquad \text{for } x \geq 1 \\
 \end{cases}$$

Comment: These $Y_k$ are correlated with $K$. The second line refers to when $K < k$. The third line refers to when $K \geq k$ (and if you like you can split that up into cases $K=k$ and $K>k$ but that does not make it less weird).

Comment: $Y_k$ depends on $k$ as: 1) being 0 when $k<K$ 2) Being uniform distributed from 0 to $\frac{x}{2}$ when $k=K$ 3) Being uniform distributed from $\frac{x}{2}$ to 1 when $k>K$. (the latter two could be combined to a case $k \geq K$)